# Add computed for each object in mapping

Tags: knockout.js, knockout-mapping-plugin

I have the following view model in my application:

```
var DashboardVM = function (serverData) {
    var self = this;
    self.tiles = ko.mapping.fromJS(serverData);
    self.someotherproperties
    ...
};
var tileData = @Html.Raw(Json.Encode(Model.Tiles));
var dashboardVM = new DashboardVM(tileData);
ko.applyBindings(dashboardVM);
```

I'd like to add a ko.computed function for each item in `self.tiles`. I've seen some examples online that suggest that it's possible, but I can't quite figure out the correct syntax to do this.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From looking at the docs, you should be able to pass some mapping options to the mapping plugin to customize the creation of the `tiles` item.  Without knowing more about your data structure it's hard to give a sample, but this might work for you:

```
var mapping = {
    'tiles' : {
        create: function(options) {
            return new specialTiles(options.data);
        }
    }
}

var specialTiles = function(data) {
    ko.mapping.fromJS(data, {}, this);

    this.tileSize = ko.computed(function() {
        return this.tileLength * 2;
    }, this);
}
```

Now when you do your mapping, pass the mapping options:

```
ko.mapping.fromJS(serverData, mapping, this.tiles);
```

Answer (score 1):

If serverData is an array you could do that. As you can see I added a computed property named *comp* which returns a text based the *title* property.

```
var DashboardVM = function (serverData) {
    var self = this;
    self.titles = ko.mapping.fromJS(serverData);
    for(var index =  0; index<self.titles().length; index++) {
        var item = self.titles()[index];
        item.comp = ko.computed(function(){
            return 'new' +item.title()
        });
    }
};
//var tileData = @Html.Raw(Json.Encode(Model.Tiles));
var titleData = [{title :'t1'}, {title :'t2'}, {title :'t3'}]
var dashboardVM = new DashboardVM(titleData);
ko.applyBindings(dashboardVM);


<div data-bind="foreach:titles">
    <span data-bind="text:title">
    </span>    
    <span data-bind="text:comp">
    </span>
    <br/>
</div>
```

**[See fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/pwtzB/)**

I hope it helps.